# other ways that can record the past habit but not mysql trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers, record

i want to record the students' height and weight every year. i am trying to make a curve of their growth.

Therefore, i plan to design a system with mysql trigger, which helps to records the data everytime i update.

However, i fail as my hosting website: http://byethost.com does not offer the sql trigger features. i am not willing to change the site as it cause many troubles. is there any other suggestions that helps to fulfill my wish or just some ways that can replace sql trigger?

Comment: Please explain why you are using a trigger. Full schema of your application may help.

Comment: i use trigger because i want to record the past data sets of the student. for example, i have to measure the student's height and weight every year. i have to update the data annually. if i can use trigger, the past data will be saved into other table. i can thus make a chart and some data analysis based on the growth of the students.

Comment: i am a newbie here and please reminded me if there is a better way to present my problem.. becoz i get a negative vote for this topic :(

Comment: Please list the tables you have

Comment: http://imm.io/XzQ8 i have print screen the table (http://imm.io/XzQ8 ) . i want to keep a record and then make a chart as it update the student information annually

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table to record past data. Insert into this table whenever you take readings. There is no need to use a trigger.